# How to get null values when the method does not return aything?

Tags: methods, null, return-value

I have 2 classes class First and class Second. There is a method in class Second

```
public void update(String reading,String writing) { 
    ArrayList1.add(reading);
    System.out.println("reading: "+reading);

    ArrayList2.add(writing);
    System.out.println("writing: "+writing);
}
```

And this `update()` method is called from class First like the following:

```
object_ofClassSecond.update(reading,writing);
```

And `classFirst` obtains these reading, writing parameters from a third class(lets call it class Third) like the following:

```
String reading=request.getParameter("reading");
String writing=request.getParameter("writing");
```

There are some other things but i dont want to go into details. So the problem is whenever there is a reading or writing I get  them from classThird and then pass them from `classFirst` to `classSecond` via the `update()` method. However sometimes this `getParameter()` method does not return anything and i need to assign the null values to my reading and writing variables in these kind of situations.  I want to see the null values in the `ArrayList1`-2 in `classSecond` whenever `getParameter()` method does not return anything.

Could you please help me to do this?

Comment: Someone edited your post and I'm not convinced it was completely valid. Review it to make sure they didn't mess anything up. You can see all the previous revisions by clicking on the text above the person who edited it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is like this, there is no change in the code and information.i can give additionally this info :

try {
     object_ofClassSecond.update(reading,writing);
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();     
 }

Answer (score 0):

> However sometimes this getParameter() method does not return anything

That's impossible. If the method is declared with a return type of `String` then any time you call it, one of three things happens:

- The method returns a reference, which may or may not be null
- The method throws an exception
- The method doesn't return at all (e.g. it has an endless loop)

Assuming your method *is* returning, it *must* be returning a value. There's no way it can return nothing at all. You should look at *exactly* what's going on in the situations where you believe it "does not return anything" and then work out what you want to happen instead.

- If the method executes forever, you'll need to work out how to break out of it
- If the method throws an exception, you need to work out what to do with the exception
- If the method is returning normally, then it must be returning a reference of some kind; if you're actually trying to use a null reference any time it returns a reference to an empty string, that's very manageable.